# Can I provide my own ads and make money off them in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ipod-touch

I've had some trouble finding information about Apple's policies regarding in-app ads. I'm interested in developing a free iOS app with the intention of making money off of it using advertising. However, I don't want to use iAds or any of the other ad providing services. Instead, I'd like to manage and deliver ads on my own.

Does anybody know if Apple has any policies regarding this? I'm assuming that I can do it, since otherwise Google and other companies wouldn't be allowed to provide their own ad-providing networks. However, would I need to give Apple a percentage of the revenue, or would I be able to keep that money for myself?

Best, and thanks in advance for any replies,
Sami

Comment: Exactly the question I was looking for, and well worded. +1!

Comment: Is your app with your own adds is approved by Apple?    I also wanted to develop an app similar to you. Is it allowed from Apple?     plz share your app name for my reference.

Comment: @Avaan I never ended up completing this project.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about app store policy, which are not allowed https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently you can.

[iAd Network iOS Developer](http://developer.apple.com/support/ios/iad-network.html)

> If I do not wish to join the iAd Network, can I continue to use my
>   existing ad delivery service?
>
> Yes. You can continue to use your existing ad delivery service even if
>   you do not join the iAd Network.